# Is there a way to find a monitor in my domain?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm running an audit of stock and have a monitor that seems to have gone missing

It will be connected to a PC that exists within a certain OU (based on geographic location) but I'm stumped at how to find this

I looked into the Get-ADComputer cmdlet, but didn't seem to have the things I needed

I have the Serial Number of the monitor, and whatever other details about it I might need. All the computers in the domain are also connected to SCCM

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure is possible, only that it would be a query against each computer thats online for that information. I believe theres a class out there you can query like [this](https://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/powershell/0073/).

Comment: You won't find any monitor information in Active Directory that's for sure.

Comment: I found this article for you using SCCM: https://exar.ch/collecting-monitor-serial-numbers-with-sccm/

Comment: `((Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer wmimonitorid -namespace root/wmi).serialnumberid | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""` could get you the serial of the monitor(s) that a computer is connected to. Essentially - you could run this command against a list of hostnames to see if any host has it connected.